Launch an Android application created with Unity from a React Native Expo application
I Have created a android application from unity and installed that into my phone. Also I have created another android application with react-native-expo. Now I need to link those two applications. So when I click on a specific button in the react-native-expo app it should launch the installed application created from unity.
I have tried expo-intent-launcher and expo-linking and both cannot open the installed application with the package name they need the apps intent's URI to open.

If you handle deep linking in your unity app you will be able to achieve your task.
However, I would suggest to create aar file from unity and load it in react native with custom native module. With this you will see single app only at end user's device.
Follow below steps for secondary option:
Step 1: create AAR file from unity and place it in react native android directory.
Step 2: update build.gradle file to include this AAR file in your RN app
Step 3: Create custom native module to open and close unity app from your RN app.
Step 4: handle this custom native method calls at desired places in your RN app
Let me know If you have any doubt in these steps.

Given that I'm using Expo, does this method work?

Yes, You can do with expo-prebuild..
